# socket.handshake can't get session

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
io.use(function(socket, next){
    signedCookieParser(socket.request, null, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log('err parse');
            return next(new Error("cookie err"));
        }
        var connect_sid = socket.request.signedCookies['connect.sid']
        console.log('connect_sid'+connect_sid);
        if (connect_sid) {
         //通过cookie中保存的session的id获取到服务器端对应的session
             sessionStore.load(connect_sid, function(error, session){
                if (error) {
                    return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
                }
                else {
                    // save the session data and accept the connection
                    socket.request.session = session;
                    next();
             }
         });
     }
    })
})
```

**i use the latest versions(1.4.4),and use this method to save the session,but i can't get the session with next method:**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    var session = socket.handshake.session;  //undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this question, but i don't know why 。

```
io.use(function(socket, next){
signedCookieParser(socket.request, null, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('err parse');
        return next(new Error("cookie err"));
    }
    var connect_sid = socket.request.signedCookies['connect.sid']
    console.log('connect_sid'+connect_sid);
    if (connect_sid) {
     //通过cookie中保存的session的id获取到服务器端对应的session
         sessionStore.load(connect_sid, function(error, session){
            if (error) {
                return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
            }
            else {
                // save the session data and accept the connection
                //socket.request.session = session;
                socket.request.headers.session = session;
                next();
         }
     });
 }
})
```

})

we set session information into socket.request.headers and we get it from socket.handshake.headers

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
      var session = socket.handshake.headers.session;  // it works
}
```

that's all.